# PageBuilder by Site Origin slowing website loading speed by 2 seconds (admin-ajax.php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have W3TC and Cloudflare Rocket Loader on my website.

Everything loads within 1 second except : admin-ajax.php

I un-installed "PageBuilder by Site Origin" plugin and these "admin-ajax.php" disappeared and the website loaded 2 seconds faster.

Is there any way to increase loading speed of "admin-ajax.php"

Have already disabled "heartbeat" but this does not increase loading speed.

Thanks

[image: Image of Requests Waterfall ..]